# QR scanning with Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision not working

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement QR code scanner in my app which already had the feature for some other module.

The project was on git, I cloned the project and tried to scan a QR code. And noticed that `ReceiveDetections` method does not detect QR code.

```
public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)
{
    try
    {
        SparseArray qrcodes = detections.DetectedItems;
        if (qrcodes.Size() != 0)
        {
            string QRcode = ((Barcode)qrcodes.ValueAt(0)).RawValue;
            ShowDetails(QRcode);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Receivedetections" + ex);
    }
}
```

I get following error:

```
Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
Failed to retrieve remote module version: V2 version check failed
Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0
Error creating remote native handle
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

I tried uninstalling `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision` package and installing it back but didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be because of _Failed to retrieve remote module version: V2 version check failed_

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: @Arti Can you give a link about this project on git?

Comment: @Leon Thanks for reply. I got it fixed just by creating new activity and copy pasting same code. Weird issue. :-(

Comment: You are welcom, VS sometime have this weird issue, when you make sure code is correct, but it still have some error, you could delete the `bin` and `obj` folder, then re-build this project, it could be solved normally. Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.